# x≡1 (mod 8) x≡9 (mod 12) has solution x = x_0. How many solutions mod 24 are there to the system of congruences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Say,

x≡1 (mod 8)

x≡9 (mod 12)

has solution x = x_0. How many solutions mod 24 are there to the
system of congruences?

I am worried this question is too easy to be true. That is why I am confused. Don't know where to start.

Comment: It is easy: you look at all the numbers from $0$ to $23$ inclusive, and see which of them satisfy the given conditions. That’s pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

Because $gcd(8, 12) = 4 \neq 1$, the Chinese remainder theorem doesn't work.
There may or may not be a solution.

First we can check, if there is a solution. 
I would split the second congruence into 2 congruences. 
$$ x  \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 4\\x \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 3$$

Because $ x  \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 8$ also implies $ x  \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 4$, the set of congruences is solvable. And the chinese remainder theorem tells us, that there is one solution $\text{mod } gcd(8,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\,\color{#c00}{a\equiv b}\pmod n\,$ then $\ \begin{eqnarray}x\equiv \color{#c00}a\!\!\!\pmod n\\ x\equiv b\!\!\!\pmod{\! m}\end{eqnarray}$ $\!\iff\!$ $\begin{eqnarray}x\equiv \color{#c00}b\!\!\!\pmod n\\ x\equiv b\!\!\!\pmod{\! m}\end{eqnarray}$ $\!\color{#0a0}\iff\!$ $x\equiv b\pmod{\!{\rm lcm}(n,m)}$

where, above, we have employed the basic lcm law: $\,\ n,m\mid x-b \color{#0a0}\iff {\rm lcm}(n,m)\mid x-b$

**Remark** $\ $ This is a special case of the uniquitous *constant case optimization* of CRT. You can find many examples of this and further discussion in [various prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+constant+optimization+crt)

Answer (score 0):

$$x\equiv1\pmod8\equiv9$$ and $$x\equiv9\pmod{12}$$

$$\implies x\equiv9\pmod{\text{lcm}(8,12)}$$